# Python profiler not showing built-in operator calls and tottime

Tags: python, profiling

Why doesn't CPython profiler show built-in operators calls and tottime ?
For example:

```
cProfile.run("for i in range(20000):a=2**i")
        3 function calls in 0.341 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.341    0.341    0.341    0.341 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.341    0.341 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



cProfile.run("for i in range(20000):a=pow(2,i)")
        20003 function calls in 0.340 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.004    0.004    0.340    0.340 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.340    0.340 {built-in method exec}
    20000    0.336    0.000    0.336    0.000 {built-in method pow}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

In the first case, most of tottime is spent in "string:1(module)", which is, to my understanding, the way the profiler tells "I'm in the string statement you gave me".
The second case however, shows more specifically the time spent in "pow"

I thought pow and ** were equivalents, ** being simply syntactic sugar, and ** was actually calling pow. It's not the case ? Or cProfile does not display built-in operators unless specified in some option ?

Thanks,

EDIT :
I understand that the profiler showing all the time spent in "+", "-" etc... is not desired behavior. My question is more about where this distinction come from : Is it because pow and ** are intrinsically different ? or because cProfile is treating them differently ?

Comment: I think it's a difference between `2 ** i` will *always* map to the built-in `pow` function, which must call `int.__pow__(2, i)`, and that function is implemented in C ; while `pow(2, i)`, on the other hand, *may* refer to a different function than the build-in `pow`, so the interpreter has to go through the full lookup routine to get the correct callable. I'm not sure how to verify this, though, short of pouring through the source code.